# How to retrieve automation name of a query via API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, automationstudio

I've been trying to identify the automation name for a query via API. Looks like theres't a way straight forward way to filter the 'AutomationInstance' objecttype upon query name. I tried using different objecttypes ended up in getting all the activities within the automation when filtered on Automation External key.

But, my request is a reverse of the above. I would like to provide 'query name' in the filter and get the automation name tied to this query. Please help. Here is the payload and response from my trials

In short - the ask is to give 'Query Name' as input and get 'Automation Name' as output.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://webservice.s6.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx'
--header 'Content-Type: text/xml;' \
--header 'SOAPAction: "Retrieve"' \
--data-raw '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
           <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
              <wsse:Username>XXXXX</wsse:Username>
              <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXX</wsse:Password>
           </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
     </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>AutomationInstance</ObjectType>
                <Properties>*</Properties>
                <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>AutomationTaskInstance.</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                    <Value>Automation_Ext_Key</Value>
                </Filter>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Did you ever work this out? If yes, please post response.